# standard way of adding button

Tags: iphone

[image]

[image]

I need to know on my navigationItem i add back, title uiSegmentedController and itemAdd button's.

Is it proper way to add that?

If it is yes..... how to add sigmentedcontroller near to ItemAdd button

Comment: Can you ask your question more specifically?

Comment: Is it proper way to add three button's on navigation Item. i added three button's on navigation item in the give picture. On is back.. another one is UISegmentedController and another one is ItemAdd style button. on the NavigationItem..... Is it proper way. to do like that.

Comment: Good Lord; all those buttons in the navigation bar are _fugly_

Comment: Yeap.....its really fugly..... i want it to be in standard passion... can you help me out. abizern

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to add back button on navigation bar if you are using a navigationController.

Assuming that you are using a navigationController just add

`self.title = @"Title";`

in the previous view.

If not than its fine

Answer (score 0):

HI

This is a proper and absolutely correct way to add buttons in the navgation controller,though you could do with a smaller back button.

Cheers